# Locking NPM version?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I am using `.nvmrc` file to lock in my Node version for my project.  Is there a way to lock in my NPM version as well?  I want to make sure that anyone that runs my project is on the same setup.

Comment: what did you do to limit the version@jjoan

Answer (score 12):

Yes. You can use the [engines](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) property in your `package.json` to specify an exact NPM version (or version range) for running your project.

Comment: how to force using the specify version, it seems only give tips right now. @pjivers

Answer (score -1):

No - nvm does not support locking the `npm` version (it is an [open feature request](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/964)).

---

Each version of `node` installs with a specific version of `npm`. The easiest way to make sure developers uses the same `npm` version would be to **use the `npm` version that comes installed with the `node` version** you specify in the project's `.nvrmc`.

In some cases, your project may be required to use a newer `npm` version while being locked to an older `node` version. Ideally you would update the `node` version along with `npm`, otherwise you'll need to document this somewhere in your project (e.g. `package.json`, `CONTRIBUTING.md`, `README.md`, etc.).